# How to store associated array with binary data for editing in notepad?

Tags: php, var-dump

I have an array and it looks like

```
$a=array('HEX'=>Chr(0).Chr(1).Chr(2),'b'=>123,'c'.......);
```

I need to store it in text file, open in text editor and edit it.

```
$fwp = fopen ('edit.txt', "wb");
FWrite($fwp,var_export($a,true));
FClose ($fwp);
```

I see that the hex data is stored as 'HEX' => '' . "\0" . [][] ''
and it seems to be lost after load-save in text editor.

So, how to store it binary-safe in php?

Comment: I think notepad on windows will strip any non-printable character when saving textfiles. Notepad is not a hex-editor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json format.
Checkout json_encode() function.
With binary data problem is little more complicated but it can be also solved.
You can convert them to base64 format with base64_encode.
Then everything will be stored in clear ASCII without any gibberish.

Comment: will it be a readable and editable for me? I mean, in text editor

Comment: Yes. It will be readable in general but binary data will be encoded into ASCII alphabet. You can read more about it here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64
Of course you have to take care of everything manually. I mean encoding proper data to base64 and then after loading file to script decoding it again.
Read here about those functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

If your data needs a structure(e.g. it's array of binary and nonbinary) use json to preserve associative array format.

Comment: hard enough for editing. I'll try to write my own function for storage and editing, but thanx anyway =))

Comment: Remeber, you can go back from base64 to binary data with base64_decode. 
json_encode() also has reciprocal function called json_decode().